# Twitter API get number of friends without all the other data

Tags: twitter

Let's say I want to do a lookup across 100 users by using: `GET users/lookup`

But I only need to know how many friends each of those users has. Is there a way of structuring the query so I don't get all the other superfluous data as shown below? If not my app is going to be too slow.

```
"time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",

"friends_count": 19,

"statuses_count": 1858,

"profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/59931895/twitterapi-background-new.png",

"status": {

"coordinates": null,

"favorited": false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to make this call lighter and thinner. You can make the call thicker by adding [Tweet entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities), but the `users/lookup` call which includes the `friends_count` is baseline. If you have a screen name or userID to work with you can make a call to [friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) , you will be returned a very basic json which includes the ids of friends. You can count the number of object in this list to get a real count of the friends.